# Guide for "Branding" Tests in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unit-testing, version-control

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC3 site that, as a platform, works great on its own - but it is meant to be branded/brandable for 3rd parties.

For the 3rd parties, it is important I keep brand-related assets and code isolated in source control, so that they don't interfere with the the assets of other brands, or of the main platform code.  And just as important, I need to have unit tests that prove the branded versions of the site are returning the appropriately branded views, etc.

At face value, it seems I need to have a Visual Studio solution file to contain the projects of the ASP.NET MVC main site platform.  I then need to have a separate VS solution for each brand (to contain satellite assemblies, custom views, etc).  The VS solution for each brand would contain a unit testing project that tests branding outcomes.

However, I don't want the branded VS solution files to hold references to the projects of the main platform site (VS project files should belong to exactly one VS solution!).  This implies that the branded ASP.NET MVC project files must have a binary dependency on the build-output of the main VS solution.  Perhaps I enlist an in-house Nuget server to aid with this.

Can anyone share guidance on the overall solution/project/folder structure of the branded projects/assets, so that the main MVC site can be integrated as merely a Nuget package?  In short, the branded materials would have a dependency on the main platorm, not the other way around.

p.s. If someone has an argument of why all the branded materials, of all 3rd parties, should indeed live in the same solution as the main platform code - I'd listen to that too.

Comment: It sounds like you need a multi-tenant implementation. Have you looked into them?

Comment: @rboarman: yes, in fact that is a selling point of Orchard CMS (which unfortunately I'm not using in this case).

Comment: Some of the links in my answer should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963919/what-to-keep-in-mind-when-developing-a-multi-tenant-asp-net-mvc-application/4964194#4964194